# Quotient of lattices and volumes

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, vector-spaces, volume, vector-lattices

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $\mathbb R$-vector space. Suppose that $L\subset V$ is a lattice (i.e. a discrete subgroup) and $M\subset L$ is another lattice, which is also a subgroup of $L$. Moreover assume that the quotient $L/M$ **is finite of cardinality $r$**. In other words we have the short exact sequence:
$$0\to M\to L\to L/M\to 0$$
The volume of a lattice $L$ is defined as:
$$\operatorname{vol}(L):=\mu(V/L)$$
where $\mu$ is the Haar measure induced on the quotient (by a fixed Haar measure on $V$). Alternatively $\operatorname{vol}(L)$ is the measure of the so called  fundamental region of $L$.

---

Given the above setting my question is the following:

> What is the relationship between the numbers $\operatorname{vol}(L)$, $\operatorname{vol}(M)$ and $r$?

I mean, for a short exact sequence **of lattices**
$$0\to M\to L\to N\to 0$$
we would have $\operatorname{vol}(L)=\operatorname{vol}(M)\cdot\operatorname{vol}(N) $. But what about the case in object?

Comment: The index of $M$ in $L$ is the ratio of volumes, in the correct order. Let $L$ be ordinary $\mathbb Z^2.$ Let sublattice $M$ require both entries even. Ratio 4 to 1.

Comment: In case of interest, Watson's paper defining his transformations used lattices in this manner http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Watson_Transformations_1.pdf

Comment: Write $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $L = A \mathbb{Z}^n$ for some matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \det(A) \ne 0$. Then $\text{vol}(L) = |\det(A)|$. Next $M = A B\mathbb{Z}^n$ for some matrix $B \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}, \det(B)  \ne 0$ and $\text{vol}(M) = |\det(AB)| = \text{vol}(L)\ |\det(B)|$ where $|\det(B)| = \# L/M$ since $L/M = A \mathbb{Z}^n/ AB\mathbb{Z}^n \simeq  \mathbb{Z}^n/ B\mathbb{Z}^n$.

Comment: It's a bit counterintuitive that the volume of the small lattice $M$ is greater than the volume of $L$

Comment: @Dubious, if we call it "co-volume", it makes more sense... Anyway, the general fact that $\int_{A\backslash C} f = \int _{B\backslash C} \int_{A\backslash B} f(ac) \;da\,dc$ (under mild hypotheses) explains the situation (realizing that sums are instances of integrals).

Comment: With that definition, the density of points of the lattice is $\frac{1}{\text{vol}(L)}$